# Doctrine is not retrieving new columns

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony4

I'm using the default find() method to get data, every thing was ok until I've added a new property to the entity : the same code is not retrieving the new column, I don't see it in the generated SQL query !

I've added other properties with different types and the problem remains : new properties aren't visible in the SQL query !

This is the result of `doctrine:schema:validate` :

```
Mapping
-------                                                                                                              
 [OK] The mapping files are correct.                                                                                    


Database
--------                                                                                                         
 [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

So it seems the schema is not ok, how can I find the problem ?

**UPDATE 1**

I have another project with no database error. I've updated an existing entity :

```
bin/console make:entity
```

Then updated the schema :

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

But the new column is not retrieved !

**UPDATE 2**

I've generated a new entity with the same properties and Doctrine returns all the columns. I've made a diff between the two entities and the two repositories : they are identical !

I've cleared Doctrine's cache  :

```
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata 
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query  
 php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

...but the problem persists

Comment: Did you create a migration? Cleared your caches? How about `doctrine:schema:validate`? Without more details we don't have much to go on..

Comment: migration > yes; c:c > yes; d:s:v : [OK] The mapping files are correct / [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

Answer (score 0):

It was a Doctrine cache issue, here is a part on my doctrine.yaml :

```
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apcu
        result_cache_driver: apcu
        query_cache_driver: apcu
```

I've tried to clear the cache `php -r "apcu_clear_cache();"` : no effect ! So I've changed the cache :

```
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: array
        result_cache_driver: array
        query_cache_driver: array
```

And now it works fine :)

Comment: CLI cache is not the same as the web cache - different memory parts. Next time run the `apcu_clear_cache` function in a web context.

Comment: thanks :) I've added ``\apcu_clear_cache ();`` at the beginning of public/index.php